# Why is Zend_Decorator_Label moved to the end of decorators array when using Zend_Form::addSubForm()?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

When I add a Zend_Form_Element to a form, I'm explicitly setting the order of the decorators, such that the errors decorator is rendered after the label.  However, when I add this form as a sub form, it changes the order of the decorators in that the label decorator is moved to the end.  What is causing this behavior and how can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.  Turns out I just made a mistake when I extended Zend_Form::addElement().